# App Insights Analytics - how to extract values and show them on daily level

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I have custom data in App Insights. The data has a structure like this:
`EventType` which can be `install` or `uninstall`. In addition to that I have `System` which can be `System1`,`System2`,`System3`...etc.

How can I get the number of installs / uninstalls per day categorized/sorted by System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
myDataSource
| summarize 
     Installs = countif(EventType == "install"), 
     Uninstalls = countif(EventType == "uninstall)
  by System
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank you!